# SQL Server connection throw exception when using Entity Framework migration - add code snippet

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a simple C# solution which has an entity class and a context class and also a console application which I use to test Entity Framework migration. But I always get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified).

Here is the connection string in the `app.config` (I put it in both console's `app.config` and context class's `app.config`):

```
<add name="ZzaDbConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Zza;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite‌​;MultiSubnetFailover=False" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I copied the connection string from "Connection string" property of the database from SQL Server ObjectExplorer so I suppose it is good.

Any suggestion why it always throws this exception?

I added entity class, context class and console class and hope this will have some clarification on my questions.

This is Entity class.

```
namespace Zza.Entities
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is Context class:

```
namespace Zza.Data
{
    public class ZzaDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is console class:

```
namespace TestEFMigration
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateDataBase();
        }

        private static void CreateDataBase()
        {
            var context = new ZzaDbContext();

            context.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Console's app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ZzaDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Zza;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

And app.config of context class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ZzaDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Zza;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Here is connection string:  <add name="ZzaDbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Zza;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: do you have any credentials in your sql?

Comment: if u have a .mdf or .sdf file u can put it's name in your connection string, try to google some connection strings maybe change of that solve the problem

Comment: @Desperado, db uses windows embedded authentication.  What credential do I need to put in the connection string?

Comment: @Saeid:  No.  I don't have a .mdf nor .sdf file.

Comment: I actually get it work if I use code based migration and use -ConnectionStringName option and assign it "ZzaDbConnectionString".  However, if I just run the program, I still see the same exception.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I reduced connection strings.

As you are using localdb, it may have trouble with some of your parameters intended for full sql server (are you aware of it?)

Differences I found are:

```
connectionString="AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Zza.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
connectionString="Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite‌​;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

So, please try removing all options on second line and adding ones on top (AttachDbFilename can be a path to the mdf you want to use/create)

```
<add name="ZzaDbConnectionString" 
 connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Zza;Integrated Security=True;
 AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Zza.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

EDIT: Ceck this

```
public class ZzaDbContext: DbContext
{
  public ZzaDbContext()
        : this("ZzaDbConnectionString") 
    {
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  My new finding is that I can run code base migration with a -ConnectionStringName option and assign "ZzaDbConnectionString" to it and it works.  But if I try to run code directly, I still get the same exception.

Comment: Could I see your context class declaration and how you create an instance? Maybe the problem is related to your dbcontext not being able to identify the connection string

Comment: namespace Zza.Data
{
    public class ZzaDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Where you instyantiate it? ie, using (var db = new ZzaDbContext()) { ... }

Comment: BTW, for dbcontext to use your connection string, it must have the same name OR you must pass the name on constructor. Please look at my edited answer.